# Perforce sync files in remote workspace

Tags: perforce

How do I sync a file at a remote location?

I am submitting  a file at a certain workspace and need that file to be synced to its latest revision in a workspace that is at a remote system?

I can obviously have scheduled task on the remote machine that syncs the file in the required workspace but I wanted to check if a simpler solution is available?

Comment: I think the scheduled task approach is a good one. I have used it in the past successfully.

Comment: @Bryan Yes,it is. But since we will have lots of remote machines that would require the updated files,using scheduled task on each seems like an overkill. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it myself but it seems the [p4 sync](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_sync.html) command takes some 
[global options](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/global.options.html).

So you could probably have a single master sync script calling :

```
p4 -c <clientA> -H <remote hostA> sync @...
p4 -c <clientB> -H <remote hostB> sync @...
p4 -c <clientC> -H <remote hostC> sync @...
```